# Using jQuery and AJAX to pass JSON data to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

I have an AJAX call using the following;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/customheader.php",
    data: { 
        update: 1,
        header : {
            1 : custom[1].header,
            2 : custom[2].header,
            3 : custom[3].header,
            4 : custom[4].header
        },
        header_key : {
            1 : custom[1].key,
            2 : custom[2].key,
            3 : custom[3].key,
            4 : custom[4].key
        }
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) ajaxSuccessCallback(this_dialog, data)

});
```

On the PHP end, I am struggling to get this data into a proper associative array to use in loops etc. I've tried;

```
$_POST['update']
```

which returns    `1`. So I know how to use JSON -> PHP when the data is not in an associative/multidimensional array.

Calling this however;

```
$_POST['header[1]']
```

returns nothing.

What is the best method for getting this multidimensional data into a proper format for iteration within PHP?

Thanks,

Comment: The proper way is `$_POST['header'][1]`

Comment: in your php script do a `print_r($_POST);` and then it should be much clearer to you how to access the data you want.

Comment: How would I get `$_POST['header']` back as an array? So if;
`$_POST['header'][1] = 1
$_POST['header'][2] = 3
$_POST['header'][3] = 5`
What do I call to get `header = [1, 3, 5]`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$_POST['header']`?

Comment: `print_r ($_POST['header']);` yields `Array`.
If it had of worked, shouldn't it print out the entire array?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` will give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

First convert it to json text first on the client side
e.g

```
var obj = {'update':1,'header':{'key1':custom[1].key,'key2':custom[2].key,'keyN':custom[N].key},...}
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

after setting up the object, use the stringify function to convert it to JSON string (please read more about the json format, it would help you in setting up the object correctly), send it with $.get() or $.post() (makes ajax request easier)

```
//example
$.get("serverside.php",{'data':jsonstring});
```

then on the server side lets say you used $.get() on the client side , you'll say

```
$str = $_GET['data'];
$Obj = json_decode($str,true);
```

then you can now say:

```
echo $Obj['update'];
```

I hope this helps, and be warned, there's lot of debugging ahead, so make good use of the internet